# I'm trying to get my output MAX value to show like this "Show Max: ##" but its only showing ###

Tags: c#

"Here it takes the Values from the textbox"

```
     //converting info from textbox
     {
        Val1 = Convert.ToInt32(Value1textbox.Text);
        Val2 = Convert.ToInt32(Value2textbox.Text);
        Val3 = Convert.ToInt32(Value3textbox.Text);
        Val4 = Convert.ToInt32(Value4textbox.Text);
        Val5 = Convert.ToInt32(Value5textbox.Text);
        //finding the maximum value
        if (Val1 >= Val2 && Val1 >= Val3 && Val1 >= Val4 && Val1 >= Val5)
        {
           Biggestint = Val1;
        }
        else if (Val2 >= Val1 && Val2 >= Val3 && Val2 >= Val4 && Val2 >= Val5)
        {
           Biggestint = Val2;
        }
        else if (Val3 >= Val1 && Val3 >= Val2 && Val3 >= Val4 && Val3 >= Val5)
        {
           Biggestint = Val3;
        }
        else if (Val4 >= Val1 && Val4 >= Val2 && Val4 >= Val3 && Val4 >= Val5)
        {
           Biggestint = Val4;
        }
        else 
        {
           Biggestint = Val5;
        }
        AnswerBox.Text = Biggestint.ToString();
```

above is where it displays the Max Value, but i want it to display max value like "Show Max:Maxvalue" but mine only shows the number. what can i do for it to display like this "Show Max:Maxvalue"???

Comment: i'm really new to this but it's interesting when it works how you want it to.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty basic stuff. I suggest you look up some tutorials! As for the answer, you can simply use `AnswerBox.Text = "Show Max: " + Biggestint;` See [channel 9 on MSDN](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners) for some basic tutorials on C#.

Comment: thanks for much man, i'm so grateful. hope i'm not to forward in asking if you can point me to the to tutorials that will help me out more. @Matthijs

Comment: As you can see I have included a link, just click on 'channel 9 on MSDN' (highlighted in blue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ruling out `Show Max:` text from the string that is going to be rendered on the screen and that is why you don't see it, add it to the code, so that it can be shown too

```
AnswerBox.Text = "Show Max: " + Biggestint.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to

AnswerBox.Text = string.Format("Show Max: {0}", Biggestint.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing all values in a list and ordering this list. Then you should find the lowesg and highest pretty easy

```
intList.OrderBy(x=> x).Last();
```

Another solution would be to use Linqs Max() Method.

intList.Max(x => x)

For the displaying aspect you should use basic string concatination or string format, or interpolation:

```
$"Max number: {BiggestInt}"
```